# Make "suggestion mode" the default intellisense mode in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

By default, Visual Studio 2015 completes what I'm writing when I hit space. This is the Intellisense "completion mode".

Instead, I want it to complete only when I press tab, which is the Intellisense "suggestion mode".

I can switch between the two by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + Space`, but every time I restart VS, it goes in "completion mode".

Is there a way to change the default to "suggestion mode"?

**Vote to request this feature**: apparently there is no way to do this. If you think this could be usefaul, please [vote for this feature on visualstudio.uservoice.com](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/12289158-could-you-please-provide-an-option-to-set-a-defaul).

Comment: Yes please, it's driving me crazy/

Comment: @willem: in the meanwhile, I have requested this feature on uservoice (see updated question). If you want, you can vote for it :)

Comment: Same issue in the latest Visual Studio 2019. (16.5.4) This feature request on UserVoice is no longer available. Have MS implemented it for VS 2015 or have they explained why they won't fix it? Just thinking if I should create similar request for VS 2019.